# Possible to use the size of a struct to create an identifier?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Say I have a function which I want to call based on the size of a type.

Is there some way this can be done using a macro?

```
static int array_find_index_4_impl(void *array, const unsigned int arr_len, const void *var)
{
    const int32_t *arr_step = arr;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_len; i++, arr_step++) {
        if (*arr_step == *(int32_t *)var) {
            return (int)i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

static int array_find_index_2_impl(void *array, const unsigned int arr_len, const void *var)
{
    const int16_t *arr_step = arr;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_len; i++, arr_step++) {
        if (*arr_step == *(int16_t *)var) {
            return (int)i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
/* etc... for other sizes too */

#define array_find_index(array, array_len, var) \
    array_find_index_##SOME_MAGIC_SIZEOF(*array)##_impl(array, array_len, var)
```

### Possible solutions...

I know C11's `_Generic` can be used to check for specific types, but I was interested in ignoring the exact types and finding the right function based on size only.

---

Another option could be to store a lookup table of functions, eg:

```
#define array_find_index(array, var) \
    array_find_index_fn_table[sizeof(*array)](array, var)
```

Which can work but would prefer to construct the identifier directly if possible.

---

*Of course its possible to pass the `sizeof` to a function and use `memcmp`, but I'm interested to know if about creating identifiers from a structs size*

Comment: Does this *have* to be done at compile time?  Could it be done pre-compilation?  I am thinking a custom source code preprocessor.

Comment: @wallyk - I guess it could... but if the solution required manipulating input C code and adding extra compilation steps, I'd  avoid the hassle and just use a lookup table.

Comment: If the lookups are always constant (which it is), doing that is unlikely to have any significant performance impact. If the table itself is constant too, the compiler might be able to optimize it down to a static call. Consider it.

Comment: Where does `arr_len` come from?

Comment: oops, added `arr_len` arg

Comment: and where `p`? and Is `var` pointer?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution could be to generate some [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) header file with the size of the relevant types, i.e. to generate a file like

```
#define MY_SIZEOF_int 4
```

etc etc.... using some simple C generating file containing

```
#define WANT_SIZE(Typ)  {              \
   printf("#define MY_SIZEOF_%s %d\n", \
          #Typ, (int) sizeof(Typ)); };
```

and have somewhere

```
WANT_SIZE(int)
WANT_SIZE(my_struct_t)
```

and running the specialized generator in the build process...

assuming some `typedef struct my_struct_st my_struct_t` before (because this works only for simply named types).

Of course, this requires complexifying the building procedure (e.g. add a couple of rules and targets in your `Makefile`...)

Yet another solution could be to use (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) its [`__builtin_type_compatible_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) or even customize it (by adding *your* specific pragmas or builtins) using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a function which I want to call based on the size of a type.
>   Is there some way this can be done using a macro?

Using only macros, no it can't be done. Macros are expended by the preprocessor, there is no awareness of an identifier's type at this stage, let alone its size.
In other words the preprocessor just doesn't have the information needed to do what you want.

However, a solution to the original problem of having a function called based on the size of a type could of course involve some preprocessing, like the one you proposed.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int array_find_index(const void *array, const void *value, size_t numOfMember, size_t element_size){//option add compare function
    size_t i;
    const char *p = (const char *)array;
    for(i = 0; i < numOfMember; ++i, p += element_size){
        if(memcmp(p, value, element_size)==0)
            return (int)i;
    }
    return -1;
}

#define ARRAY_FIND_INDEX(array, var) \
    array_find_index(array, var, sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array), sizeof(*array))

int main (void){
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int ikey = 3;
    int index = ARRAY_FIND_INDEX(ia, &ikey);
    printf("%d\n", index);
    char ca[] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
    char ckey = '5';
    index = ARRAY_FIND_INDEX(ca, &ckey);
    printf("%d\n", index);
    ckey = '0';
    index = ARRAY_FIND_INDEX(ca, &ckey);
    printf("%d\n", index);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: array_find_index is only an example, the question is about the C preprocessor.